# Understanding relationship direction of Model fields in Django

Tags: python, django

I have used Django for quite awhile but not sure I fully grasp how the relationships should work. this is best described in example so here goes. Let's assume there is a `Company` which has several `Departments` and each `Department` can have several `Role`s in it. Then, each `Role` can have several `Employees`.

The questions come about how the fields should be laid out when it comes to accessing the data. Some of the questions that come up may seem obvious and may be better understood as I write them out but bare with me because I am using this to learn.

Should it be:

Example 1 (redundant):

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = charfield
    departments = m2m(Department)
    roles = m2m(Role)
    employees = m2m(Employee)

class Department(models.Model):
    name = charfield
    roles = m2m(Role)
    employees = m2m(Employee)

class Role(models.Model):
    name = charfield
    employees = m2m(Employee)

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = charfield
```

Example 2 (not redundant):

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = charfield
    departments = m2m(Department)

class Department(models.Model):
    name = charfield
    roles = m2m(Role)

class Role(models.Model):
    name = charfield
    employees = m2m(Employee)

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = charfield
```

Example 3 (fields look upwards):

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = charfield

class Department(models.Model):
    name = charfield
    company = FK(Company)

class Role(models.Model):
    name = charfield
    department = FK(Department)

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = charfield
    role = FK(Role)
```

Example 4 (redundant, fields look upwards):

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = charfield

class Department(models.Model):
    name = charfield
    company = FK(Company)

class Role(models.Model):
    name = charfield
    department = FK(Department)
    company = FK(Company)

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = charfield
    role = FK(Role)
    deparment = FK(Department)
    company = FK(Company)
```

It seems to me that #3 is the best option as each `Employee` belongs to a `Role` and if I need to access the `Department` or `Company` linked to that `Employee` I can access it through `employee.role.department.company`. But then the question would be about how accessing reverse relationships would go; if I had a `Company` and need to get all the `Employee`s then I would have to do reverse relationships all the way down, right? Each direction seems to have a tradeoff.

Am I thinking through this right? How should the architecture be structured and why? What else could I be missing here and what reasons would I build the models in another manner?

Thanks for your help!

Edit: With option 3 it seems you could just do this and have less data consistency issues:

```
class Role(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_employees(self):
        return self.employee_set.all()
```

Comment: Unless you have a more complex relationship, such as a department belonging to multiple companies (not sure that makes sense), then FK is the way to go.  I had a similar situation recently, and I actually went with your option 4 over option 3.  The reverse lookups just got too complex (for me), and I didn't think having extra fields would matter that much.  But I do not have experience with large scales, so I'll let more experienced developers chime in.

Comment: The problem I see with Option 4 is data getting crossed, making debugging difficult. e.g. If you have an `Employee` who is in `Department` 1 and `Role` 1 but `Role` 1 gets applied to `Department` 2, then you could have an issue with data inconsistency if your filters are not consistent. This is actually a problem I have in a current app and one of the reasons I asked. As my first big project, I went with Option 4 to reduce complexity and it seems to have bitten me down the road with data inconsistency bugs every now and then; which could have been mitigated.

Comment: I never thought about what would happen if the FK of an above model changed.  Yes, I could see how that would be problematic.  You could write code to automatically update the FK of all other objects on down, but unless that is something that happens only occasionally, it would not be desirable.  I'm going to see what happens when I change my own models to Option 3, and see how the reverse look-ups would work.  Best of luck.

Comment: If you have company and wat to retrieve the employees, you can do a [reverse lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) from employees, filtering based on company Example using example 3: `Employee.objects.filter(role__department__company__name="company 1)`

Comment: Or... the way I suggested in the edit of the post. But that doesn't really answer any of the questions I had :)